# How to use Android phone desktop fix-rotated?

Tags: background-process, screen

I have Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos GT-i9082 Duos Android 4.2.2 mobile phone. Normally whether I open "Screen Rotation" or not, the desktop holds itself as vertical. (Picture 1) Today, in faulty maybe, I captured rotated desktop screen (Picture 2), and I thought, why couldn't we use our phone screen fix-rotated? Is there a option to select that? Can I rotate it without any app. installed?

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]
[image]

Comment: may be rooted device can done

Comment: By "fix-rotated", did you mean landscape mode (as seen on 2nd image)? Android phone usually has "locked screen rotation" setting, although it's location vary by phone model. Also, it might be impossible on some phones to force landscape mode.